# Perceptron (single layer 2D) - Result with samples on straight line

Tags: r, machine-learning, pattern-recognition, perceptron

I tried to implement a simple 2D single layer perceptron and ended up with this solution:

```
perceptron <- function(featureVec, classVec, wStart=matrix(c(0,0,0)), eta=1, limit = 50) {

  plot(x=featureVec[,1],y=featureVec[,2])

  # Extending dimensions
  dimension <- dim(featureVec)[1]
  featureVec <- cbind(featureVec,rep(1,dimension))

  # Inverting 2. class
  index <- classVec == -1
  featureVec[index,] <- apply(matrix(featureVec[index]),1,prod,-1)

  wTemp <- wStart
  y <- featureVec %*% wTemp

  iteration = 0
  while (T) {
    y <- featureVec %*% wTemp
    delta <- as.matrix(featureVec[y <= 0,])

    for(i in 1:nrow(delta)) {
      wTemp <- wTemp + eta*delta[i,]
    }
    result <- featureVec %*% wTemp
    if (sum(result <= 0) == 0) {
      break
    }
    if (iteration >= limit) {
      stop("Maximum count of interations reached!")
    }
    iteration = iteration + 1
  }  
  if(wTemp[2] != 0) {
    abline(-wTemp[3]/wTemp[2],-wTemp[1]/wTemp[2])
  } else if(wTemp[2] == 0) {
    abline(v=wTemp[1])
  } else if(wTemp[1] == 0) {
    abline(h=wTemp[2])
  }

  return(wTemp)
}
```

The feature vector works row-wise, the class vector needs values of 1 and -1 col-wise.

For most of my tests it works correct, but when I have samples like `(0,0) (0,1)` with classes `(1,-1)` I get no result. That happens with some of my examples with two points lying on a straight line (horizontal to a coordinate axis). When I try to choose different start vectors it sometimes works correctly (I have no deterministic behaviour here right now I guess). Is that a correct behaviour or is my implementation wrong?

Thanks for your help, Meiner.

EDIT: Some changes of the inital post.

Bad Dataset:

```
featureTest <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1),byrow=T,nrow=2)
classTest <- matrix(c(1,-1),nrow=2)
perceptron(featureTest,classTest)


featureTest <- matrix(c(0,1,0,2),byrow=T,nrow=2)
classTest <- matrix(c(1,-1),nrow=2)
perceptron(featureTest,classTest)
```

Good Dataset:

```
featureTest <- matrix(c(0,0,0,2),byrow=T,nrow=2)
classTest <- matrix(c(1,-1),nrow=2)
perceptron(featureTest,classTest)
```

Comment: Can you provide a "good" data set and a "bad" dataset and the command you use to run it?

Comment: Yes, I changed my initial post.